# Simple Sorted Linked List Issue

Tags: c++, c++11

Working through problems in a Data Structures book I bought and am having trouble getting my Sorted Linked List to compile. The sorting function is where I am running into trouble. The goal is to just input a number, add that number to the list in sorted position, print the list. I am just trying to sort using very basic comparative operators but I cannot get it to function. 
Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated.

Issue Code Below:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node* next;
    int data;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    Node* head;

    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void add(int data);
    void print();
    void sorting();
};

void LinkedList::sorting()
{
  Node* head = this->head;
  Node* node = new Node();

  for (Node* current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
  {
      if (head->data > head->next->data)
      {
          node = head;
          head = head->next;
          head->next = node;
      }

      head=head->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your source contain method bodies for the `print()` and `add()` methods?

Comment: @the_storyteller Yes, but those methods/functions work perfect. These section of code is the only one with trouble.

Comment: You don't seem to be using `current` in your `for` loop at all?

Comment: @Stubbsy Your loop keeps going, even after you've supposedly inserted the item.  You're supposed to insert the item, and once the item is inserted, exit the function, right?  So why don't you `return` from the function, instead of continuing to loop?

Comment: You have nothing that can possibly ever change `this->head`. How do you see the first item getting inserted into an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

> The sorting function is where I am running into trouble. The goal is to just input a number, add that number to the list in sorted position, print the list.

Does it mean `sorting()` is responsible for inserting a new node at sorted position in the list? Does not look like so as you are not sending anything in the parameter.

However, I am assuming that is the case. Now back to your code. Instead of using `current`, you are using `head` everywhere in the `for` loop. This is surely messing with your list. Try the updated code and I hope your code should do fine.

```
void LinkedList::sorting(int data)
{
    for (Node* current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    {
        // for ascending sorted list
        if (current->next->data > data)
        {
            Node *node = new Node();
            node->data = data;
            node->next = current->next;
            current->next = node;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```